# Removing a letter from a string at a specific position

Tags: java, string

I am trying to locate the * in a string and remove it and the characters in front and before it.
for example the string st*tilly will output silly

this is what I have so far

```
public static String starOut(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == '*') {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
            sb.deleteCharAt(i);
            sb.deleteCharAt(i+1);
            sb.deleteCharAt(i-1);
            sb.toString();
        }
    }
    return sb;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this.  It uses a regular expression

- `.` matches any character.
- `\\*` matches an asterisk. It has to be escaped because by itself it has a special meaning in regular expressions.

```
String str = "The sx*yilly dog was acting very st*tilly";
str = str.replaceAll(".\\*.","");
System.out.println(str);
```

Prints

```
The silly dog was acting very silly
```